# HDD light is showing disk usage very high at times. How to investigate?

Tags: hard-drive

How should I go about investigating seemingly high disk usage?

From time to time the whole system crashes too - I think the high HDD reads/writes might be to blame.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can monitor what programs are causing how much IO by running `iotop`.

Comment: Turns out Tweetdeck, Firefox, Gwibber and Thunderbird are causing the most read/writes. I had apt-get remove'd gwibber though - not sure why that's still showing up.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to too look at the disk utility and take a look at the SMART Data, this gives you a good overall view of how healthy your disk is/isn't.
[image]

Comment: Thanks. I had done short scans before and it came back fine. Just did a full test and still everything fine. Think it was just too much multitasking.

Comment: +1 My disk was showing similar simptoms last several months. Now it is most probably mechanically failing. Archiving!!...

Answer (score -1):

Did you skip creating a swap partition when you installed Ubuntu? If you did, add a new swap partition.

In GParted Format a partition as "linux-swap" and then right click swapon.

I had the same problem too, and this helped me.