# Excessive hard disk access on secondary HDD, I'm not accessing anything on it

Tags: 11.10, mount, hard-drive

I've set up my Ubuntu 11.10 on a SSD with an encrypted LVM. I've attached another ext4 HDD, unencrypted, it's automounted on `/media/data` and created Videos, Music, Downloads and Backups folders on it, removed the existing ones from my home folder and symlinked the new ones.

My PC is constantly rattling from hard drive usage although I am not accessing any of those folders. Like, create a new tab in Chromium, 2 seconds of HD rattle. `ll /etc` (which is on the SSD), 1 second of HD rattle. Open new terminal window, 2 seconds of HD rattle and then it's open.

Automatic backup is on, but set to run weekly. What is going on here? Did I mess something up?

Comment: Where is your swap space located?

Comment: SSD. Also, got 8 GB RAM with not much load, so I don't think that's a problem.

Comment: Even with 8 GB of RAM it is still possible for memory to be stored in swap, simply because it leaves more room for sudden memory surges. `lsof` is your best friend here, find out what files are open

Comment: Try this linked question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/37304/hdd-light-is-showing-disk-usage-very-high-at-times-how-to-investigate

Comment: I don't know how I can investigate it... `iotop` lists resource hogs, it don't say which process is accessing `/media/data`. `lsof` takes ages to print the open files, so if I open a new window with Ctrl-Shift-N and then issue `lsof | grep media` I get nothing.

Comment: OK, got it. This is one of those "axe questuns first, think laterz" type of deals. Turns out I had a swap partition on the 2nd drive from god knows when and my current install helped itself to it. Removed entry from `/etc/fstab`, killed the partition and I got a quiet rig again. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

This was solved by the OP

> Turns out I had a swap partition on the 2nd drive from god knows when and my current install helped itself to it. Removed entry from /etc/fstab, killed the partition and I got a quiet rig again